# How to include a primitive called runtime in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Most Lisp implementations include a primitive called `runtime`.
I use `DrRacket` and when I press `Run` I see `runtime: unbound identifier in module in: runtime`. How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following equivalent functions:

```
(define (runtime) (current-milliseconds))
```